# ios xcode: product name does not equal value for Target settings -> Packaging -> Product Name -> (Debug|Release)

Tags: ios, xcode

Xcode driving me crazy. I'd like my DEBUG product to be called "ProductName-Dev" and my ADHOC product to be called "ProductName-Beta" and my RELEASE product to be called "ProductName". I want then all on my device at the same time.

I selected my Target, then Packaging, then Product Name, then Debug (or another config) and set the names I would like. Different schemas are based on the different configurations.

It build OK regardless of the schema I select, but does not create a .app in the Product group.

If I try to run any of the schemas in the Simulator it launches and then immediately quits. For the DEV schema the name in the status area is ProductName-Dev, but for the others it is just ProductName.

Clearly I don't understand this. Appreciate your help.

Todd

[image: img]

[image: img]

Comment: Did you set a different bundle ID for your three configurations? If not, you will see only one icon on your device. You can do so by user a user-defined variable.

Comment: Many thanks, I know this is an old one. I never did solve it! This sounds exactly the issue. Will try it!